# How to call the router from within a middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm building an api and I need to validate the key from within a middleware, so I want to call the router like this:

```
$this->getRouter()->input('key')
```

How would you go about this?

I also want to pass some results to the controller, so that I don't have to process the key again.

Comment: Did you try `$request->key`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to get the input as you say, the middleware already has the $request variable passed to it. You can simply call the key from the Request object given.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $key = $request->get('key');
    ...
```

If you're asking for the specifics of the route it's applied on you may need to rethink your strategy of what middleware does what. If you just wanted to massage the data and other various things for a specific controller then you may want to look into this being done on the controller constructor. If many controllers need it create a subcontroller of the parent controller that handles the key manipulation. Middleware as far as I know isn't meant to really handle business logic.